# Error when plotting HoltWinters graph

Tags: r, exception, plot

The following R code is giving me an error when trying to plot the HoltWinters graph as done [here](http://a-little-book-of-r-for-time-series.readthedocs.org/en/latest/src/timeseries.html):

```
# init X
X11()

# get data
mydata = read.csv("lookup.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# data post-proc
mydata = as.data.frame(mydata)
mydata$Time = as.POSIXlt(mydata$Time, format='%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S')

# create time series - hourly data -> 8765 hours/year
dataTimeSeries <- ts(mydata$Close, frequency=8765)

dataForecasts = HoltWinters(dataTimeSeries, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)

# output
plot.ts(dataForecasts)
message("Press Return To Continue")
invisible(readLines("stdin", n=1))
```

The error I'm getting is:

> $ Rscript simple_forecast.R
>
> > Error in xy.coords(x, NULL, log = log) :
> >
> > > (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
> >
> > Calls: plot.ts -> plotts -> xy.coords
> >
> > Execution halted

I'm quite perplexed, since *print(dataForecasts)* prints the correct data. I can also plot *dataTimeSeries* without a problem.

[lookup.csv](http://pastebin.com/UgSktLA2) (pastebin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally one should rely upon R to do the dispatch of class-dependent functions, and do notice that the example you cited at Avril Coghlan's page only used `plot`, not `plot.ts`.

```
 (m <- HoltWinters(co2))
 plot.ts(m)
Error in xy.coords(x, NULL, log = log) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

 plot(m) # success
```